# JavaScript Encoding & Decoding Error

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I am getting an issue with Javascript Encoding and Decoding. I have a json object which contains a string encoded in UTF-8 like `'R\xc3\xa9union'`. To ensure that the Javascript file correctly displays the string, I'm adding an attribute charset to the script tag. The json object is in `countries.js`. I'm including countries.js as `<script src="js/countries.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>` and yet it is still being displayed as **RÃ©union** instead of **Réunion**. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you adding encoding to HTML document too?

Comment: Yes, I'm adding this: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Can you include a JSFiddle? It may be a problem in which the server sends the data.

Comment: unfortunately, I've too many dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) combined with [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent):

```
decodeURIComponent(escape('R\xc3\xa9union'));
```

That should do the trick:

```
escape('R\xc3\xa9union');           // "R%C3%A9union"
decodeURIComponent("R%C3%A9union"); // "Réunion"
```

Now, you said you couldn't do this manually for all the places you need strings from the JSON. I really don't know a way to automate this without re-building the JSON with JS, so I'd suggest writing a little "wrapper" function to decode on the fly:

```
function dc(str){
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(str));
}
```

You can then decode the required strings with minimal effort:

```
var myString = dc(myJson["some"]["value"]);
```

Now, what else *could* work, but is a little more risky: [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the entire object, decode that using the 2 functions, then [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it again.

Comment: this definitely does the trick, but I'm using the json string on loads of places, i cannot manually do it

Comment: @Noor: As far as I know, there is no "automatic" way of letting JavaScript know how to interpret those strings. I've added a little suggestion on how to do it semi-automated.